# Will it be a good practice to extend the Struts Framework's FilterDispatcher?

Tags: java, struts2, servlet-filters

I am trying to use Hibernate with Struts. Will it be a good pratice if I extend the `FilterDispacther` for calling Hibernate Utility classes?

Anyone have any views? I want to discuss the pros and cons with this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't extend `FilterDispatcher`.

As duffymo indicated, if you need to set up and tear down a Hibernate session for the current request, you should use an interceptor. You can use the `OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` that he linked too, or if you don't use Spring, you can [create your own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901137/hiberate-with-struts2-use-full-hibernate-plugin-or-another-method-to-close-sess/5903530#5903530).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want to have functionality similar to Spring's [OpenSessionInViewInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html).  If yes, the fact that another framework has already done such a thing suggests that it is a good practice.

Comment: i don't know spring. but the problem is that the `FilterDispatcher` is deprecated.

Comment: Why not just a Filter?  What's the FilterDispatcher doing for you?

Comment: `public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
  super.init(filterConfig);
  try{
   HibernateUtil.createSessionFactory();
   System.out.print("========= Application Intialization ========");
  }
  catch (HibernateException e) {
   throw new ServletException();
  }
 }`

FilterDispatcher is just openning a session. nothing else..

Answer (score 0):

The point is usually you don't want to map a filter to all your requests - For example you don't need a transaction for some pages - The api doc for FilterDispatcher says that

> IMPORTANT: this filter must be mapped to all requests. Unless you know exactly what you are doing, always map to this URL pattern: /*

So FilterDispatcher is all or nothing. Which tells a old good Filter is a better choice for open session in view pattern.