# How to know DriverManagerDataSource has a connection pool

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, tomcat, connection-pooling

I have a question about the `DriverManagerDataSource` in Spring.

Our microservice uses Spring Boot and Hibernate to connect to Druid Database. We use  `DriverManagerDataSource` to create our `dataSource` instance. From the documentation of `DriverManagerDataSource`, we know that it does not have a proper connection pool implementation.

However, when we tested the microservice, we can see 10 *established* TCP connections when we increased the query load to 10 concurrent virtual users, and those 10 connections remained *established* even after the queries completed. They only reduced to 1 connection after we initiated a new query with only 1 concurrent virtual user.

The above symptom indicates that there is indeed a connection pool established. I am pretty confused at this point: where is this pool coming from?

I tried the test mentioned [here](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-how-to-know-which-connection-pool-is-used/), but I got

```
Datasource = org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource@xxxx;
```

(pls ignore the xxxx). The following is a partial pint out of the microservice's startup that shows Tomcat started:

```
[30m2024-03-12 10:03:27,567[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [[34mmain[0;39m] [33morg.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog[0;39m [,] - Starting service [Tomcat]`
[30m2024-03-12 10:03:27,568[0;39m [34mINFO [0;39m [[34mmain[0;39m] [33morg.apache.juli.logging.DirectJDKLog[0;39m [,] - Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.86];
```

I am not sure if Tomcat JDBC's connection pool automatically kicked in?

Comment: Cannot see where did you use your data source. If you use hibernate then you might get leaked connections remaining open they just keep week references to your database.

Comment: @RomanC Hello, can you explain what you mean by where I used my data source? Our dataSource instance is created as a bean and autowired to other places. Thanks.

Comment: Well I think you didn't use any data source. In the link you have posted I only saw `javax.sql.DataSource` which was autowired to the spring boot application. The implementation provided by third party vendors.

Comment: @RomanC I see, thanks for that info. May I know what you suggestion is then? Should I switch from DriverManagerDataSource to HikariDataSource which is a true data source and have proper connection pooling implemented?

Comment: Yes, you can switch a data source, it won't work however. You didn't read my previous comment. "Well I think you didn't use any data source."

Comment: @RomanC I am confused by your previous comment; we are using Druid DB as the datasource so I am not sure where you got that impression from. The link I provided is just a method to test what connection pool / datasource type a spring application is using; it is not my implementation...

Comment: It is not a connection pool, hibernate used to cache connections and reuse them if needed. Read below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DriverManagerDataSource.html) is not a connection pool. It is a simple implementation of `javax.sql.DataSource` which was autowired to the spring boot application.

> Simple implementation of the standard JDBC DataSource interface, configuring the plain old JDBC `DriverManager` via bean properties, and returning a new `Connection` from every getConnection call.
>
> **NOTE: This class is not an actual connection pool; it does not actually pool `Connection`s.** It just serves as simple replacement for a full-blown connection pool, implementing the same standard interface, but creating new `Connection`s on every call.
>
> Useful for test or standalone environments outside a Jakarta EE container, either as a `DataSource` bean in a corresponding `ApplicationContext` or in conjunction with a simple JNDI environment. Pool-assuming `Connection.close()` calls will simply close the `Connection`, so any `DataSource`-aware persistence code should work.
>
> This `DriverManagerDataSource` class was originally designed alongside Apache Commons DBCP and C3P0, featuring bean-style `BasicDataSource/ComboPooledDataSource` classes with configuration properties for local resource setups. For a modern JDBC connection pool, consider [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) instead, exposing a corresponding `HikariDataSource` instance to the application.

If you use Hibernate, you should read

> [Chapter 1.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch01.html)
>
> 1.1. Connecting
> Hibernate connects to databases on behalf of your application. It can connect through a variety of mechanisms, including:
>
> Stand-alone built-in connection pool
>
> `javax.sql.DataSource`
>
> Connection pools, including support for two different third-party opensource JDBC connection pools:
>
> c3p0
>
> proxool
>
> Application-supplied JDBC connections. This is not a recommended approach and exists for legacy reasons
>
> **Note:
> The built-in connection pool is not intended for production environments.**
>
> Hibernate obtains JDBC connections as needed though the `ConnectionProvider` interface which is a service contract. Applications may also supply their own `ConnectionProvider` implementation to define a custom approach for supplying connections to Hibernate (from a different connection pool implementation, for example).
>
> [Chapter 3.3 JDBC Connections](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/configuration-hibernatejdbc.html)
>
> Hibernate's own connection pooling algorithm is however quite rudimentary. It is intended to help you get started and is not intended for use in a production system or even for performance testing. You should use a third party pool for best performance and stability. Just replace the `hibernate.connection.pool_size` property with connection pool specific settings. This will turn off Hibernate's internal pool.

> [Hibernate data sources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25452029/573032)
>
> If you are not configured data sources then Hibernate will use
>
> ```
> hibernate.connection.provider_class = org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider
> ```
>
> This connection provider has in-built rudimentary connection pool for which you can set a `hibernate.connection.pool_size`, but it is used only for development purposes. Never use it in the production environment.

> [Hibernate connection pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14567812/573032)
>
> In your hibernate configuration implicitly used `DriverManagerConfigurationProvider`. This provider used by default unless you configured it with property `connection.provider_class`.
>
> > This provider also implements a very rudimentary connection pool.
>
> What it means "rudimentary connection pool". If you run your application you can see in the logs
>
> ```
>    [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] >Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>    [DriverManagerConnectionProvider] >Hibernate connection pool size: 20
> ```
>
> You can also set this value via hibernate configuration property `connection.pool_size`. But *it doesn't limit you to the maximum opened connections count.* You can open as many as you need connections while pool is empty. The provider will keep them open as it returns connections to pool on `closeConnection` unless the current pool size not exceeds the value in the property `connection.pool_size`. Once current pool size is not empty you cannot open any new connection because the connection provider returns connection from the pool.

Comment: Thank you! That has resolved all my confusions. I really appreciate this.