# How to put object in ThreadLocal in Struts 2?

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to open Hibernate `Session` on each request and close it at the end.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901137/hiberate-with-struts2-use-full-hibernate-plugin-or-another-method-to-close-ses) seems like it could work, but I have now idea how am I supposed to put my `Session` object in `ThreadLocal` and answer does not explain that.

Is there any Struts2 specific way to do this?

Comment: Spring can manage Hibernate session for you. Look for Spring OpenSessionInViewFilter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a HttpFilter that is in front of the Struts2 Servlet. In the filter:

```
public class SessionProviderFilter implements Filter {
    private static ThreadLocal<Session> sessionStore = new ThreadLocal<Session>();


    public void doFilter(...) {
        Session session = ... // get the session
        sessionStore.set(session);
        chain.doFilter(...);
        sessionStore.set(null);
   }

   public static Session getCurrentSession() {
        return sessionStore.get();
   }
}
```

Now from any code, to get current hibernate session, you call SessionProviderFilter.getCurrentSession().